# IntegrityError: (1451, 'Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (..))

Tags: python, django, admin, m2m

when deleting users with schedule_files I got this:

> IntegrityError at /admin/auth/user/166/delete/
>   (1451, 'Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`vacation`.`vacations_schedulefile`, CONSTRAINT `vacations_schedulefile_user_id_e85fa52f_fk_auth_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `auth_user` (`id`))')

My models are:

```
class ScheduleFile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    added = models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return '[User ID: {}] {}'.format(str(self.user.id), self.user.username)
```

And

```
class VacationEvent(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    schedule_type = models.CharField(choices=SCHEDULE_TYPES, default=STRICT_TIME, max_length=3)
    exclude_fba_from_chatzos = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    schedule_file = models.ForeignKey(ScheduleFile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(verbose_name="status event", choices=EVENT_STATUSES, max_length=3, default=CREATED)
```

And User(AbstractUser)
I decided to create pre_delete signal and delete relative objects of schedule model:

```
@receiver(pre_delete, dispatch_uid='User')
def user_del(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    i = instance
    events = VacationEvent.objects.filter(user_id=166)
    schedule = prefetch_related_objects(events, 'schedule_file__user')
    schedule.delete()

# instance.user.schedulefile_set.clear()
# qs = VacationEvent.objects.filter(user_id=166).prefetch_related_('schedule_file')
# qs.delete()


# b = ScheduleFile.objects.filter(user_id=166)
# e = VacationEvent.objects.filter(user_id=166)
# e.schedule_file.remove(b)
```

But it returns 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'delete'. How can I do it right? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can not delete ScheduleFile because it's primary key is required by
VacationEvent so you have to delete VacationEvent record before the 
ScheduleFile model this can be done in several way by signal or overriding 
delete function on ScheduleFile model

example:

```
def delete(self, using=None):
    if self.schedule_file:
        self.schedule_file.delete()
    super(ScheduleFile, self).delete(using)
```